# How to use file:duplicate from the palette using plugin in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext3

How to use `File : duplicate` option from the palette using plugin in sublime  text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see which command is being run when a particular action is being performed, open the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>) and run

```py
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

Next, open the Command Palette (`command: show_overlay {"overlay": "command_palette"}` will show up in the console) and select **`File: Duplicate`**. The console will close, but when you reopen it you will see that `command: side_bar_duplicate {}` has been logged. At this point, you can enter

```py
sublime.log_commands(False)
```

to stop logging, as it tends to fill the console with unnecessary garbage.

As you can see from the name of the command, **`File: Duplicate`** is from the [`SideBarEnhancements`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements) plugin (defined [here](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements/blob/st3/SideBar.py#L1610)) and is not built-in to Sublime. Therefore, if you are making a plugin for public distribution, you users will need to have SideBarEnhancements installed first.

To call this (or any) command in your plugin, simply put

```py
window.run_command("side_bar_duplicate")
```

into your code at the appropriate location.

As @OdatNurd reminded me, because `SideBarDuplicateCommand` is a subclass of `sublime_plugin.WindowCommand`, it can only be run on an instance of [`sublime.Window`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.Window).

Comment: `side_bar_duplicate` is a `WIndowCommand`; as such, a `view` can't execute it and you'd need to use `window.run_command()` instead. Also, the argument should be the name of the command as a string, e.g. `window.run_command('side_bar_duplicate')`

Comment: @OdatNurd thanks, I forgot about the quotes. I made the changes you suggested, but I had a question: I was under the impression that you could run a `WindowCommand` on a view and it would just send it up the line to the view's window. Is that not the case?

Comment: EDIT: was that ever the case? I see it's not the case now...

Comment: Not in my experience, no (for ST3 at least). a `window` can execute any command and will direct a `TextCommand` to the currently focused view (including input widgets), but the reverse is not true. In addition, `sublime.run_command()` can only execute an `ApplicationCommand`. So generally speaking, `window.run_command()` is the most foolproof way to execute something if you're not sure what kind of command it is.

Comment: @OdatNurd Ah, it must have been the reverse I was thinking of. Good to know, thanks

Comment: @MattDMo log_commands log side_bar_duplicate for me in fresh windows version